# while posting data into database using forms in django data is not saving

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

while posting data into database through django forms data is not saving.

Here is my model class :

```
   class data(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       age = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
       mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
       password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

forms.py file :

```
  class datamodel(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = data
            fields = ('name', 'age', 'mobile', 'email', 'password')
```

view.py file :

```
   def template_2_data(request):
       form = datamodel()
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = datamodel(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
              data = form.save(commit=False)
              data.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
              data.age = form.cleaned_data.get('age')
              data.mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
              data.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
              data.password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
              return HttpResponse('data saved...')
    else:
          form = form
          return render(request, 'template_2.html', {'form': form})
```

Template :

```
 <form action="/template_1/temp_1/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't save the `data` instance and it is not automatically saved because you have `commit=False`. Add a `data.save()` line right before `return HttpResponse()`. Why do you manually fetch form data instead of letting form save it?

Comment: i added data.save() but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for above question :

```
def template_2_data(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = datamodel(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
       return render(request, 'template_2.html', {'form':form})
```